# Change order/position of nodes in plot of networkx

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

I am having a pandas dataframe and want to plot a network based on the dataframe. The current plot looks like:
[image]

It starts in the right above corner and goes to the left one. If i plot it the next time, it can have a different starting position, how can I avoid it? And furthermore how can I set the starting node into the left above corner and the end node (which i can also decline upfront) set always in the right down corner?

My code until now is:

```
###make the graph based on my dataframe
G3 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df2, 'Activity description', 'Activity followed', create_using=nx.DiGraph(), edge_attr='weight')

#plot the figure and decide about the layout
plt.figure(3, figsize=(18,18))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G3, scale=2)

#draw the graph based on the labels
nx.draw(G3, pos, node_size=500, alpha=0.9, labels={node:node for node in G3.nodes()})

#make weights with labels to the edges
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G3,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G3, pos, edge_labels = edge_labels)
plt.title('Main Processes')

#save and plot the ifgure
plt.savefig('StandardProcessflow.png')
plt.show()
```

packages I use is networkx and matlotlib

Comment: To partially answer your question - you can set a `seed` in `nx.spring_layout`, like `pos=nx.spring_layout(G3, scale=2, seed=42)`. See if it helps.

Comment: `seed=1` does look resonable for me, what does it do? Is it the same approach like random_state?

Comment: yes, like explained below by @vurmux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [seed](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html#networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout) attribute of `spring_layout` to prevent your graph nodes from moving each draw:

> **seed**
>
> `(int, RandomState instance or None optional (default=None))` – Set the random state for deterministic node layouts. If int, seed is the seed used by the random number generator, if `numpy.random.RandomState` instance, seed is the random number generator, if `None`, the random number generator is the `RandomState` instance used by numpy.random.

Or specify a layout by yourself, like:

```
pos = {
    1: [0, 1],
    2: [2, 4]
    ...
}
```

You can combine both methods:

```
G3 = nx.Graph()
G3.add_weighted_edges_from([
    (1,2,1),
    (2,3,2),
    (3,4,3),
    (3,6,1),
    (4,5,4)
])

pos = nx.spring_layout(G3, scale=2, seed=84)
pos[1] = [-20, 0]
pos[5] = [20, 0]

nx.draw(
    G3,
    pos,
    node_size=500,
    alpha=0.9,
    labels={node:node for node in G3.nodes()}
)

edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G3,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G3, pos, edge_labels = edge_labels)
```

[image]

You can use it if you want to set particular nodes in special places.

Comment: for the pos[1] do i need to write the integer, or is it also possible to write the label? so for example pos['Milkman']

Comment: You need to write node IDs there. If you use words for them (I guess), you should write them like you wrote in your comment.